# Redirection to other page after ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that i use to add data to my database. I am using Ajax.BeginForm() to post data to the controller and then execute a stored procedure to save data. The result that i want is to show an error if the stored procedure fail to add data and to redirect to an other page in the other case. So I did something like this in my controller.

```
    if (succees)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ModificationPage", new { id = posted.articleId });
    }
    else
    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = msg;
    return PartialView("_error");
```

_error is a simple partialview which display the error message. My problem is that when the stored procedure add data, instead of redirecting to the modification page, the modification page is rendred inside the view. Is there a method in asp mvc that can fix this

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, then just do a standard submit (there is no real benefit in using ajax) and then if there is an error, add a model state error and return the view or redirect to an error page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is what am actually using, but the problem is that when there is an error i have to refresh the page and that takes a lot of time and with ajax i just update a small portion of the page

Comment: No your not. Your using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which is an ajax call. Just use `Html.BeginForm()` and do a standard submit if you want to redirect.

Comment: I mean that i used the Html.BeginForm() and now i want to modify it and use Ajax.BeginForm()

Comment: Your question clearly says _I am using Ajax.BeginForm() to post data to the controller_! But if you really are using `Html.BeginForm` then stick with it, and if you have an error, add a `ModelState` error and return the view to display the error, or redirect to an error page to display the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onSuccess parameter of ajaxForm

```
   using( Ajax.BeginForm( "action","controlle",
                   new AjaxOptions( ) {
                       OnSuccess = "mySuccessFunction",
                   } ) ) }
```

And then in js

```
function mySuccessFunction(){
  //check if html with error exist on page
  window.location = "url"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` is not supported in ajax. You could send the redirect URL back to the client and from the client use `window.location` to redirect to the new location.

Answer (score -2):

you can in your controlleur

```
 if (succees)
    {
        Redirect("/AREA/ContolleurName/ModificationPage/?Id=" + posted.articleId+ ")

    }
    else
    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = msg;
    return PartialView("_error");**strong text**
```

and create action in your conrolleur

```
public ActionResult ModificationPage(int Id)
        {
return //your view 
}
```

Or ajax like this

```
    $("class(.test) or Id (#Test)").on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        /*Création de la chaine en Json...*/

        window.location.href = "/AREA/ContolleurName/ModificationPage?Id=" + id  +"";


     });
```

Comment: It is not possible like this in the controller, I already test it